# cannot load ftp file from ftp

Tags: asp.net, xml, http, ftp

I want to put an xml file in http password protected directory.
when its not protected with passsword i put the http full path and it work
but when I try to access from the code there is an exception:

```
       XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
         try
         {
             xdoc.Load("http://user:password@mysite.com/safe/users.xml");
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             return false;
         }
```

the exception is: 401 means unauthorized.

if I type the line:
http://user:password@mysite.com/safe/users.xml
in my borwser -> i can see the xml file.

thanks !

Comment: The XmlDocument is not relevant to the question. Try to get the content using Webclient or WebRequest. Can you do this succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to supply network credentials for the XmlResolver

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47as68k4(v=vs.71).aspx

```
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader("hthttp://@mysite.com/safe/users.xml");
rdr.XmlResolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(rdr);
```

and here is the link for setting upt credentials.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.71).aspx